# installing gnome on my ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: gnome, software-installation

I'm trying to install the gnome desktop environment on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS using the command line:

```
$sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

but the terminal keeps saying:

```
"Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method of installation and you may not face any issue:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

To install all the GNOME 3 apps:

> sudo apt-get install bijiben polari gnome-clocks gnome-weather
>   gnome-maps gnome-music gnome-photos gnome-documents gnome-contacts
>   epiphany-browser gnome-sushi gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions
>   gnome-tweak-tool

copy paste these commands in terminal one-by-one.

**NOTE:**"The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature. Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge, when you encounter issues"

Comment: after the apt-get dist-upgrade line, the terminal states: <The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
>

Comment: @user3463764 on up synaptic package manager and search for this "gnome-settings-daemon-schemas" and right click to install/upgrade and then tell me